# kotlin.io.NoSuchFileException: The source file doesn't exist when the .txt file exit

Tags: android, kotlin

This .txt file that I am attempting to copy does exist when I check the folder. However whenever I attempt to do a copyTo, the error the source file doesn't exist is being shown and the source file does not get copied. I am not quite sure how to fix this error. This is the code:

```
binding_second.btnDone.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            var this_dir = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), this_filename)
            println(File(getExternalFilesDir(null), this_filename))
            var target_dir = File("/storage/sdcard/Download/"+ this_filename)
            this_dir.copyTo(target_dir)
        }
    })
```

This is my android manifest:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="tallify.greengoldindustries.tallify">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Tallify">
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited: Just added more details

Comment: `This .txt file that I am attempting to copy does exist. I am not quite sure how to fix this error. ` If a file exists then why are you talking about an error? Which error?

Comment: The file exist when I check it in the file directory but an error stating the file does not exist is being thrown when I attempt to make a copy of that file.

Comment: `println(File(getExternalFilesDir(null), this_filename))` Dont set up a file path twice. Use the first one: println(this_dir) And why not println(this_file) ?

Comment: `The file exist when I check it in the file directory` You are not checking that in code. Please add that code and also code for canRead().

Comment: Make sure "/storage/sdcard/Download/" exists as well. I believe you would get the same exception if the destination dir would not exist.

Comment: Not only exists but also check canWrite() for destination directory before trying to copy anything.

Comment: `var target_dir` ? target_file?

Comment: `file that I am attempting to copy does exist when I check the folder. ` I wonder how you check that as for instance on Android 11 that directory is not visible for file manager apps.

Comment: @broot thanks for pointing me in the right direction! The target_file does exist but apparently my this_dir does not exist. I am on Android 7.0 so can check the data folder and the file exist. Do you have an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I have managed to fixed it by getting the absolute path of the file. Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused with your variable naming and what is the source and what is the target. But generally speaking, if you have a file path where you need to place a resulting file, e.g.: `val targetFile = File("/storage/sdcard/Download/some/path/somefile")` and `(...)/some/path` dir does not exist, you will get an exception. To create the dir: `targetFile.parentFile.mkdirs()`.